# Make column and insert array contents inside the column.

Tags: powershell

I am reading in CSV file, after that I use -match to find a pattern I am looking for.  I now have all of my matches inside a variable called $results. Next, I would like to create a new column and insert the contents of $results into that column.  I have been stuck on this for a while, I have attempted to use for loops, forEach loops, if statements, and I cannot seem to get the results that I am looking for.   I am new to Powershell, so I may be missing something obvious.  Any help is greatly appreciated!
  Here is my code:

```
 $target = "This is the path to the .CSV file"
 $pattern = '(V-\d*)'

 $TestFile = (Get-Content $target) 

 $results = $TestFile | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches 
 $results.Matches.Value 



 #$TestFile -replace '(V-\d*)',' '

 $NewFile = ConvertFrom-Csv $TestFile|  Select-Object *,@{Name='Generic 
  Header';Expression={"Unsure of how to input data here without having all 
  data in same row"}}|export-csv ' Path for Exporting New .CSV file' -notype
```

Comment: Can you show us some part of the CSV file (sanitized of course)

Comment: I cannot, all I am doing is taking strings from one column, storing them in results, creating new column, inserting contents of results into the new column.

Comment: So, is your input file really a CSV file (multiple columns, headers) or just a text file with strings on separate lines?

Comment: Still unclear to me what you are after, insert/append the new column to what? To get the results in one column => `$NewColumn= $result -join ','`

Comment: Yea, the input is also a CSV.  Multiple headers, etc. (Theo) .  I apologize, but I cannot show you the file, everything would need sanitized. But its a reg. CSV file with about 5 headers in there and multiple rows.

Comment: (LotPings)  I tried that with results.Matches.Value earlier and it returned all captured patterns on the same line for every row.

Comment: Hard to help without some sample input.

Comment: I appreciate all of your time and answers however LotPings was able to answer my question successfully, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample csv file with pattern in varying columns before

```
> import-csv  .\SO_54012419.csv

col1  col2  col3
----  ----  ----
foo   bar   V-123
V-345 foo   bar
bar   V-789 foo
```

running this script:

```
$target  = ".\SO_54012419.CSV"
$pattern = '(V-\d*)'

$csvdata = Import-Csv $target | Select-Object *,Result

foreach($row in $csvdata){
  if ($row -match $pattern){
    $Row.Result = $Matches[1]
  }
}

$csvdata
$csvdata | Export-Csv 'Path for Exporting New.CSV' -NoTypeInformation
```

and after:

```
col1  col2  col3  Result
----  ----  ----  ------
foo   bar   V-123 V-123
V-345 foo   bar   V-345
bar   V-789 foo   V-789
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped tremendously.  Can you please explain the significance of using $Matches[1], I know matches returns every matched item, but this is the first I've seen the use of [1], again I'm new to P-Shell.  Thanks

Comment: The `-match` operator fills the $Matches collection, where $Matches[0] represents the whole input, $Matches[1] the first capture group in the pattern `()` $Matches[2] the 2nd etc. See `Get-Help about_comparison_operators` or [view online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Thanks for the info.!  Been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think this should do it:

```
$target  = "This is the path to the .CSV file"
$pattern = '(V-\d*)'
$column  = 'The name of the column to perform the regex match on'

# Read the input file as array of PSCustomObjects
$content = Import-Csv $target

# Do a foreach loop on each of the objects in the $content array
# and perform the regex -match on it. Add a new property (column) to every
# object in the array with the result of your regex match. 
# Add an empty string if no match was found.
foreach ($item in $content) {
    if ($item.$column -match $pattern) {
        $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Result' -Value $matches[1]
    }
    else {
        $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Result' -Value ''
    }
}

# now use Export-Csv to write the new file complete with the new 'Result' header
$content | Export-Csv 'Path for Exporting New .CSV file' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hmm displays the header, but the column is empty.

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct header name in the `$column` variable then?

Comment: That makes more sense than first treating the csv as text (unless the match could be in any column). A `Select-Object` with a calculated property could also contain the if command.

Comment: @LotPings I agree. The OP however is not willing to show some of his input csv file, but he did say "_all I am doing is taking strings from one column_".

Comment: @Theo thank you for your time, I was able to get the desired result using another example.  Again, apologize for not being able to show a scrubbed version, but do to the nature of my work I could not.  Thanks again.